# PHPUnit only recognizes three of my four tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a class containing four unit tests. The class looks like this:

```
class TestWorkflowService extends TestCase
{
    private $containerMock;

    private $workflowEntityMock;

    private $workflowService;

    public function setup()
    {
        $this->containerMock = $this->createMock(ContainerInterface::class);
        $this->workflowService = new WorkflowService($this->containerMock);
        $this->workflowEntityMock = $this->createMock(WorkflowInterface::class);
    }

    public function testGetWorkflowProcessByEntityNullResult()
    {
        self::assertNull($this->workflowService->getWorkflowProcessByEntity($this->workflowEntityMock));
    }

    public function testGetProcessHandlerByEntityNullResult()
    {
        self::assertNull($this->workflowService->getProcessHandlerByEntity($this->workflowEntityMock));
    }

    public function testRestartWorkflow()
    {
        $modelStateMock = $this->createMock(ModelState::class);
        $processHandlerMock = $this->createMock(ProcessHandler::class);
        $processHandlerMock->method('start')->willReturn($modelStateMock);
        $this->containerMock->method('get')->willReturn($processHandlerMock);
        self::assertNull($this->workflowService->restartWorkflow($this->workflowEntityMock));
    }

    public function setEntityToNextWorkflowState()
    {
        $modelStateMock = $this->createMock(ModelState::class);
        $processHandlerMock = $this->createMock(ProcessHandler::class);
        $processHandlerMock->method('start')->willReturn($modelStateMock);
        $this->containerMock->method('get')->willReturn($processHandlerMock);
        self::assertNull($this->workflowService->setEntityToNextWorkflowState($this->workflowEntityMock));
    }
}
```

... but when I run PHPUnit, I get this result:

> ...                                                                 3
>   / 3 (100%)
>
> Time: 2.17 seconds, Memory: 5.75MB
>
> OK (3 tests, 3 assertions)

Why is my fourth test not being recognized?

Comment: Shouldn't the `setEntityToNextWorkflowState` method need to startwith `test`?

Comment: Thanks. It should indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPUnit identifies test methods using the [following rules](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html):

> The tests are public methods that are named test*.
>
> Alternatively, you can use the @test annotation in a method's docblock to mark it as a test method.

This is so you can have other public methods in your test class without them being interpreted as tests (although I'm not sure why you'd ever actually do this).

Change your method name to `testSetEntityToNextWorkflowState`, or tag it with the `@test` annotation.

Comment: dataprovider methods it a test case should be public